# Resfresh page in the function onChange on an Input text

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to change the value of VARS when changing the value of a text input. Is there anyway of refreshing the page using events as onBlur or onChange and get the new value of the text input? I cant use any submit buttons. All the variables used are in PHP.

I want to change the value of:

```
    $_SESSION['unidades'][$id];
```

By introducing a value in this input:

```
echo "<td colspan='3'><input type='text' value=" . $_SESSION['unidades'][$i];     
echo " size='2'/>";
```

All help and ideas appreciated.

Comment: Please explain you question in more detail, it is not clear

Comment: @Steve I have a VAR[quantity] wich I want to change its value by introducing a new value in a text input but I cant use any submit buttons. I dont know how to explain it more clear.

Comment: And where is your `VAR['quantity']` in javascript, or in PHP?

Comment: @lolka_bolka Oh, sorry, Its all on PHP. I have little notions about JS. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thing you could do is using jQuery `$.post` and using JavaScript.

Each time you enter a new value in the `input` box, you could make the jQuery do a `$.post` with the new value to a `.php` file that change "the value of VARS".

Comment: I will take a look about post funcionts in JQuery. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just call location.reload(true) to refresh the page and force it request all the changes again on the onchange parameter

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: Ok, I use that function to refresh my page. But how do I get the new values of the inputs? I really dont know too much about JS.

Comment: If your page need to send any information to the server before it be reloaded, you cant do a refresh on the page, cause it will not send anyone. You can either use an ajax request like mentioned above by @Padness, or use the javascript window.location adding the value of your variable on the adress bar. Example: window.location = 'www.page.com?unidades=' + document.frm.field.value